# Delay response to a HTTP request without blocking

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-2.x, python-multithreading

How can I code an HTTP server where the responses are not sent synchronously?

I would like to enable:

1. Request 1 arrives
2. A synchronous service deals with request 1, but doesn't block the main thread
3. During that, request 2 arrives, and is dealt with in its own unique way
4. Request 1 returns to the client
5. ... etc.

But it looks like as soon as the `do_GET` or similar methods reach their end, the server is sending a response to the client. It is too late for me to send my own response later.

For example

```
import time
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from threading import Thread


class HTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        # I have some code that MUST run on the main thread during do_GET
        run_something_on_main_thread()
        # and some code that I really don't want to
        responder_thread = Thread(target=self._respond_later, args=(self.wfile,))

    def _respond_later(self, wfile):
        u""" Query some blocking service, then respond to the request """
        time.sleep(2)
        wfile.write('HTTP/1.0 204 No Content\n\n')
        wfile.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_address = (u'0.0.0.0', 8000)
    http_server = HTTPServer(server_address, HTTPRequestHandler)
    print u'Starting httpd server on {}:{}'.format(*server_address)
    http_server.serve_forever()
```

Querying this server always results in empty replies.

Ideally I would love a way to do this that allows me to use `send_response`, `end_headers` etc. — all the convenience methods from `BaseHTTPRequestHandler`. Above, I pass the `wfile` because I was wondering if it would be "frozen" in the new thread, I really don't expect passing `self` to work (because I think all its methods would be pointed at the new request, not the request relevant at the time of the creation of the thread).

So how do I delay the response to the client without blocking the main thread?

Comment: Reason it's failing is because [right after calling that convenience method the wfile is flushed](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/http/server.py#L415) and I assume cleaned up and stuff. I know [threaded versions exist](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/socketserver.py#L682) but I don't think they are as high level as you'd like.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen how can I stop the wfile from being flushed automatically? Adding a custom `handle_one_request` method to my own class doesn't seem to have fixed it.

Comment: Note: The module you're using clearly isn't designed for non-blocking or high performance behavior, quoting its own docstring: "The classes in this module favor the server type that is simplest to write: a synchronous TCP/IP server.  This is bad class design, but saves some typing." The short answer to your question is: Use a third party framework that *is* designed for this sort of thing.

Comment: as this is an uncommon pattern, I suggest it will be better off to write your own 
 http server, juggling with all those threads.